# I get "':mergeDebugAssets"-Error when compiling my App with Ionic

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

Hello Stackoverflow Team,

when i run the following command:

```
ionic build android
```

I get the following:

```
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'.
```

> [www/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /home/felix/Entwicklungen/TryMe/platforms/android/assets/www/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js    [www/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /home/felix/Entwicklungen/TryMe/platforms/android/assets/www/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [www/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /home/felix/Entwicklungen/TryMe/platforms/android/assets/www/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js  [www/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /home/felix/Entwicklungen/TryMe/platforms/android/assets/www/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [www/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /home/felix/Entwicklungen/TryMe/platforms/android/assets/www/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js.gz [www/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /home/felix/Entwicklungen/TryMe/platforms/android/assets/www/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [www/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /home/felix/Entwicklungen/TryMe/platforms/android/assets/www/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js.gz   [www/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /home/felix/Entwicklungen/TryMe/platforms/android/assets/www/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js: Error: Duplicate resources

When I just compile a blank app, everything works fine. Can someone tell me whats happened here? 
I also tried to remove platform android and add it again but nothing happened. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to delete the semver directory.

Comment: there's 2. which one? I am pretty sure I tried deleting each, uninstalling each and reinstalling each to no effect.

Comment: In my project was only 1 semver directory. When I  deleted it, everything was fine...

Comment: What I actually ended up doing to fix this was to delete the compressed files from my semver directory as it appears cordova gets confused between the .gz and .js resources.

Comment: @catbadger that's definitely the issue. thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent a long time trying to fix the same problem on my computer, after creating a new windows user.

I tried deleting the .gz-files, but for one of my plugins, the .gz-files was recreated every time I ran

> $ ionic cordova run android

I tried different versions of android platform-tools, build-tools etc..
Different cordova versions.. Different node and npm versions.

I also messed around with the environment variables.

But what I finally discovered (and what I suspect caused the problem for me), was that I hadn't correctly cloned the repository from bitbucket.

I had used:

> git clone
>   https://**creators_username**@bitbucket.org/creators_username/repository_name.git

instead of:

> git clone
>   https://**my_username**@bitbucket.org/creators_username/repository_name.git

After cloning again, using my own username, everything seems well. And I haven't got any node_modules folders inside

> platforms/android/assets/www

or it's subfolders. And my theory is, you're not supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **build** folder inside **www** and try again.. good luck.